400 Bad Request From Htmx Post To .Net Razor Page
I've been out of the FE game for a while having specialised in back-end API development in .Net around 4-5 years ago so forgive me if this is a simple one but it's a project using Razor Pages and Htmx, both of which I am just dipping my toes into.
I've been following this tutorial from Jetbrains as a gentle introduction to Htmx
https://www.jetbrains.com/guide/dotnet/tutorials/htmx-aspnetcore/htmx-counter/
Unlike the tutorial, I am using .Net 8 for the backend portion.
The issue I face is for me, my counter page is returning 400 bad request when following along with the code they are demonstrating.
I have a Counter razor page which has a simple button that triggers an empty hx-post to the current page and is supposed to replace the contents of the target div with the new value from the server. Pretty straightforward. Except despite following their example to the letter, I am receiving a 400 bad request when I hit the button.
My Razor Page code is as follows:
<!-- Counter.cshtml -->

@page
@model Counter
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Counter";
}

<div class="card p-5 mb-4">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>
            <!-- change the button -->
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
                    hx-post=""
                    hx-target="#example_one_count"
                    hx-vals="">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
                Increment
            </button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2 id="example_one_count" class="fs-2" style="text-align: right">
                <span>0</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

And on the backend my handlers are as follows:
<!-- Counter.cshtml.cs -->

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace HtmxWebApp.Pages;

public class Counter : PageModel
{
    private static int count = 0;
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
        // reset on refresh
        count = 0;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        // TODO: Increment the count on each request
        return Content($"<span>{++count}</span>", "text/html");
    }
}

I know that Htmx is included and working correctly as it's injected into the _layout template and I can see that the previous example I ran through replacing content with a get request works absolutely fine, but I'm just not sure what gives with this.
Is it possibly a change to how post is handled in Razor Pages in .Net 8? Like I said, I'm an API developer so I only work with .Net Core Web Apis so I'm not longer familiar with the ins and outs of Razor Pages as I never need to use them
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's a simple one but I've tried everything.

For anyone else who might stumble across the same tutorial in 2024 or beyond, what they don't tell you is if you want to do these examples in your own project you need to ignore the anti-forgery token used in Razor Pages that is supposed to be sent up on post requests.
Because they use a button, this sends the data up as a form as part of the post and the backend is therefore processing and expecting an anti-forgery token to be present.
After looking into their full final project code, they have this in their Program.cs
// Add services to the container.
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(o => {
    // this is to make demos easier
    // don't do this in production
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});

As the class name suggests, this ignores the anti-forgery token meaning the post request will be processed as is.
Do not use this in any production code and be aware that if you do use the htmx-post in production you will need to find a way of including the anti-forgery token as part of what you pass back to the server.
For further reading, the following blog post as to how to properly handle the anti-forgery-token in Htmx.
It can be found below:
https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/htmx-requests-with-aspnet-core-anti-forgery-tokens
